# PintOS, kernel panic with -v option bochs on ubuntu

Tags: operating-system, bochs, pintos

when i do "pintos -- run alarm-multiple" in .../build/ everything seems fine.

but when i do "make check" in .../build/ all 7 tests failed with the same
"Run didn't start up properly: no "pintos booting" message"

`pintos -v -k -T 60 --bochs  -- -q  run alarm-single < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/alarm-single.errors > tests/threads/alarm-single.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/alarm-single.ck tests/threads/alarm-single tests/threads/alarm-single.result
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-single
Run didn't start up properly: no "Pintos booting" message`

then I discovered "pintos -v -k -T 60 --bochs  -- -q  run alarm-single" in .../build
it gives a

Bochs is exiting with the following message:
  [     ] bochsrc.txt:12: display library 'nogui' not available

if I take away the "-v" it will be fine.

How to fix this 
  display library 'nogui' not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nobody seems to answer me... I got that myself at last.
just need to change the bochs's configure : ./configer --with-nogui
and then compile it again:

make

sudo make install

After that pintos's make check will work.

Answer (score 1):

i had same problem and i solved it.
open "/pintos/src/tests/Make.tests"
edit line 54 (delete -v)

```
TESTCMD = pintos -v -k -T $(TIMEOUT)
```

then, in "/threads/build" you can do

```
make check
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember when you using Ubuntu 14.04 or 16.04, never forget doing such things when you download original pintos project or any pintos project from Github.

```
(Any line with no parentheses are terminal commands)
cd ~
gedit .bashrc

(add next line to the final of the file)
{export PATH="$PATH:/home/{username}/pintos/src/utils"}

(save)
bash

cd ~/pintos/src/utils
gedit Makefile
(You need to change one line)
{change LDFLAGS = -lm to LDLIBS = -lm}
(save)
make
```

Then you can compile and run "make check" for pintos with no error.

(Any ~/pintos should be changed to your pintos path)

Remember final make in ~/pintos/src/utils is ridiculously important. Otherwise you will get "Run didn't start up properly: no "Pintos booting" message".

You can check full version here. http://www.luosheng-parallelbgls.com.cn/2016/03/29/pintos-install/
Cause this is a Chinese version, I would appreciate for anyone who can translate it to English.