# Pintos, make check failed. Run didn't start up properly: no "Pintos booting" message

Tags: linux, operating-system, bochs, pintos

I found that someone has asked a relevant question before [PintOS, kernel panic with -v option bochs on ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15354286/pintos-kernel-panic-with-v-option-bochs-on-ubuntu/)

However, I tried but it didn't work. "pintos -- run alarm-multiple" seems fine but when I do "make check"

`......
Run didn't start up properly: no "Pintos booting" message
pintos -v -k -T 480 --bochs  -- -q -mlfqs run mlfqs-block < /dev/null 2> tests/threads/mlfqs-block.errors > tests/threads/mlfqs-block.output
perl -I../.. ../../tests/threads/mlfqs-block.ck tests/threads/mlfqs-block tests/threads/mlfqs-block.result
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-block
Run didn't start up properly: no "Pintos booting" message
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-single
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-multiple
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-simultaneous
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-priority
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-zero
FAIL tests/threads/alarm-negative
FAIL tests/threads/priority-change
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-one
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-multiple2
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-nest
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-sema
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-lower
FAIL tests/threads/priority-fifo
FAIL tests/threads/priority-preempt
FAIL tests/threads/priority-sema
FAIL tests/threads/priority-condvar
FAIL tests/threads/priority-donate-chain
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-load-1
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-load-60
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-load-avg
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-recent-1
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-fair-2
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-fair-20
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-nice-2
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-nice-10
FAIL tests/threads/mlfqs-block
27 of 27 tests failed.
../../tests/Make.tests:26: recipe for target 'check' failed
make: *** [check] Error 1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem today and it was because i was trying to set **qemu** as the default simulator so I changed line 103 in **utils/pintos** to

```
$sim = "qemu" if !defined $sim;
```

but i forget to change the **SIMULATOR** value in **threads/Make.vars** to

```
SIMULATOR = --qemu
```

Since I didn't setup bochs on my machine `make check` was trying to run the tests on it but if fails to boot.

**Note** that this is one scenario why tests fail to run, it could be another reason but since

```
pintos -- run alarm-multiple
```

is working fine, I think this might be the same problem you have.